# Dynamic parameter as part of request URI with Apache HttpCore

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am looking for existing solutions to match dynamic parameters with HttpCore. What I have in mind is something similar to constraints in ruby on rails, or dynamic parameters with sails (see [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes) for example).

My objective is to define a REST API where I could easily match requests like `GET /objects/<object_id>`.

To give a little bit of context, I have an application that creates an `HttpServer` using the following code

```java
server = ServerBootstrap.bootstrap()
            .setListenerPort(port)
            .setServerInfo("MyAppServer/1.1")
            .setSocketConfig(socketConfig)
            .registerHandler("*", new HttpHandler(this))
            .create();
```

And the `HttpHandler` class that matches the requested URI and dispatches it to the corresponding backend method:

```java
public void handle(final HttpRequest request, final HttpResponse response, final HttpContext context) {

        String method = request.getRequestLine().getMethod().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT);
        // Parameters are ignored for the example
        String path = request.getRequestLine().getUri();
       if(method.equals("POST") && path.equals("/object/add") {
           if(request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) {
           addObject(((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)request).getEntity())
       }
       [...]
```

For sure I can replace `path.equals("/object/add")` by something more sophisticated with RegEx to match these dynamic parameters, but before doing so I'd like to know if I am not reinventing the wheel, or if there is an existing lib/class I didn't see in the docs that could help me.

Using HttpCore is a requirement (it is already integrated in the application I am working on), I know some other libraries provide high-level routing mechanisms that support these dynamic parameters, but I can't really afford switching the entire server code to another library.

I am currently using httpcore 4.4.10, but I can upgrade to a newer version of this might help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present HttpCore does not have a fully featured request routing layer. (The reasons for that are more political than technical).

Consider using a custom `HttpRequestHandlerMapper` to implement your application specific request routing logic.

```
final HttpServer server = ServerBootstrap.bootstrap()
        .setListenerPort(port)
        .setServerInfo("Test/1.1")
        .setSocketConfig(socketConfig)
        .setSslContext(sslContext)
        .setHandlerMapper(new HttpRequestHandlerMapper() {

            @Override
            public HttpRequestHandler lookup(HttpRequest request) {
                try {
                    URI uri = new URI(request.getRequestLine().getUri());
                    String path = uri.getPath();
                    // do request routing based on the request path
                    return new HttpFileHandler(docRoot);

                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    // Provide a more reasonable error handler here
                    return null;
                }
            }

        })
        .setExceptionLogger(new StdErrorExceptionLogger())
        .create();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll manage to make it work with the `HttpRequestHandlerMapper`